# Two thread shared static variable

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-overflow, shared

I want to run a simple server-client program where clients checks each 5 sec best server and connect always best server. So I wrote following code but I get stackoverflow error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        RTT best = null;
        BestServer bestserver = new BestServer(best);

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(bestserver.bestserver.ip, 6789);
        System.out.println("I connect best server");
}   

public class BestServer implements Runnable{

    static RTT bestserver;

    public BestServer(RTT best) throws InterruptedException{
        bestserver = best;
        findBest();
    }

    public static void findBest() throws InterruptedException{

        Thread t = new Thread(new BestServer(bestserver));
        t.start();
        t.sleep(5000);
}

public void run(){
    //..
}
```

Comment: Is this the client or the server? If it's the server you may want to look at the ServerSocket class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

Comment: No it is client. Client connects always best server in terms of rtt, and he checks bestserver each 5 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `StackOverflow` comes from this line.

```
while(true){
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(bestserver.bestserver.ip, 6789);
    System.out.println("I connect best server");
}
```

You make Sockets until you run out of memory.

You need to make a set amount of sockets, otherwise you'll always run out of memory.

Another problem is these two lines:

```
public BestServer(RTT best) throws InterruptedException{
    bestserver = best;
    findBest();
}

public static void findBest() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread t = new Thread(new BestServer(bestserver));
}
```

One calls `findbest()`, and the other calls the constructor. Since this is the case, one will call the other until you run out of memory.

Comment: But even i delete while, i still have the same error